# ComboBox of objects ignores toString method

Tags: swing, jcombobox, tostring

Hi guys i got such kind of trouble[image: Object name insted of caption]

In dialog w/ combo box

```
    public JComboBox<IngrMeasureUnit> getUnits(){
     JComboBox<IngrMeasureUnit> result = new JComboBox<IngrMeasureUnit>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < parent.getIngrList().imul.getSize(); i++ ) {
            result.addItem(parent.getIngrList().imul.getMeasureUnit(i));
        }        
     return result;
}
```

And the class

```
public class IngrMeasureUnit {

private int id;
private String name;
private boolean mustInt;

public IngrMeasureUnit( int id, String name, boolean mustInt ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.mustInt = mustInt;
}

public String toSrting() {
    return name;
}
```

Cannot understand such behauviour, because in other cases it works.
Tried to put @Override annotation, the compiler rejected it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is named `toSrting()` instead of `toString()`. Always use the `@Override` annotation when your intention is to override a method. That way, if you don't, the compiler will emit an error:

```
@Override
public String toSrting() { // compiler error, because toSrting() doesn't override anything
```

*Tried to put @Override annotation, the compiler rejected it.*

The compiler rejected it precisely because the method doesn't override anything. The error means: you want to override a method, but you don't. Something is wrong. Instead of removing the annotation in this case, you should fix the method signature.

Comment: lol, thanks a lot, actually i found that mistake few hours ago